# “A friend of my brother“ or “A friend of my brother's”?

Tags: possessives, exam-questions

I got to learn that it's incorrect to say *A friend of my brother*. The correct clause should be *A friend of my brother's* but I don't know the reason why it is so.

I found a discussion [on a forum](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/a-friend-of-his-wifes.2438592/) on the same topic but still couldn't understand why it’s incorrect to say *A friend of my brother*. Doesn't the *of* in the clause work as apostrophe?

Comment: Please see [this post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12126/why-use-apostrophe-s-to-denote-possession-when-using-of).

Comment: Why do you think "A friend of my brother" is wrong. Who told you? The linked forum suggests that both are acceptable.